# How can i change the background color from a javascript file

Tags: javascript, html, css

html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.div1 {
background-color: blue;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<script src="test.js"></script>
<div id="dd" class="div1" onmouseover="mousecolor()" onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor=null">
<p>hep</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

javascript file

```
function mousecolor() {
    console.log("hhhhhhh")
    document.getElementById("dd").style.BackgroundColor = "000080"
}
function mouseout() {}
```

the console does seem to be working when i hover over the text, but the background color doesn't change

Comment: `backgroundColor`, not `BackgroundColor`

Comment: @RobinZigmond tried that too, still doesn't work

Comment: Also missing the `#` for the new hex value string

Comment: @charlietfl yeah that was it, thanks

Answer (score 1):

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        .div1 {
        background-color: blue;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="dd" class="div1" onmouseover="mousecolor()" 
onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor=null">
        <p>hep</p>
    </div>
    <script src="test.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript

```
function mousecolor() {
    console.log("hhhhhhh");
    document.getElementById("dd").style.backgroundColor = "#fcba03";
}
```

Used the color #fcba03 and changed `BackgroundColor` to `backgroundColor`. Worked for me

Answer (score 0):

The code as given does work apart from the need to change BackgroundColor to backgroundColor in the JavaScript assignment to style.

On moving the mouse over the color changes from a bright blue to a dark (navy) blue.

Note that the mouseout action is rather strange - null is not a color. Possibly it was meant that the color be set to transparent:

```
onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor='transparent';
```

Note the use of single quotes around the string that is the color (in this case transparent).